# Looping through raster layers in folder with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, loop

I'm looking to apply a mask to a number of rasters in PyQGIS.
(updated but still not working)

```
import processing
rstr = "/Users/rasterfilepath/"
shp = "/Users/shapefile.shp"
outputDir = "/Users/output/"

for lyr in rstr:
  processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", rstr, shp, "none", False, False, "", outputDir + lyr + ".tif")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get, if any? What is not working as expected and what would be the expected result?

Comment: Hi Kersten, thanks for the fast reply!
Error: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects (Line 3)

Comment: for loops don't require a line like `lyr +=1`.  lyr is a string and the plus sign with a string is concatenation.  So, it's trying to concatenate the layer name and 1.  take that line out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a couple of things to notice:

1. In your algorithm, you are using `rstr` (the path of the rasters) as the input instead of the actual rasters which you have defined as `lyr`.
2. This probably depends on the **Processing plugin version** but in v2.10.2, the algorithm `gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer` requires 7 parameters (you mentioned 6). You can check this by using the Python console:

   ```
   import processing
   processing.alghelp("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer")
   >>>ALGORITHM: Clip raster by mask layer
          INPUT <ParameterRaster>
          MASK <ParameterVector>
          NO_DATA <ParameterString>
          ALPHA_BAND <ParameterBoolean>
          KEEP_RESOLUTION <ParameterBoolean>
          EXTRA <ParameterString>
          OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
   ```
3. Lastly, you could use the following code to loop through rasters in a specified folder. I like to use the [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to search for specific types of files alongside setting the current directory with [**`os.chdir`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to the path containing the files:

   ```
   import glob, os, processing
   rstr = "/Users/rasterfilepath//"
   shp = "/Users//shapefile.shp"
   outputDir = "/Users/output//"
   os.chdir(rstr)    # Sets the current directory to your rasterfilepath
   for lyr in glob.glob("*.tif"):
       processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", lyr, shp, 'none', False, False, '', outputDir + lyr)
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can eliminate the use of `os.chdir()` by calling `glob.glob(os.path.join(rstr, "*.tif"))` and get the full paths. I find this preferrable in scripts, so users don't encounter sudden directory changes.

Comment: @Kersten - Thanks buddy, that also sounds like a good alternative.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help but I am still having trouble with this. I am not a Windows user so cannot use the glob solution. I updated the text above, can anyone offer any advice please?

Comment: @Dazzle - `glob` is a Python module, I don't think it matters which OS you use. Did you install QGIS via the OSGeo4W Installer?

Comment: Hi Joseph. No just installed QGIS v2.10.1 as normal on macbook. Still no luck with glob or other methods

Comment: just got it to work!! Woohoo!

Comment: @Dazzle - Haha nice! What did you do?

Comment: The glob module worked as soon as I set os.chidr. I would still like to complete the task without the use of glob however

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

[For looping folder to batch clip rasters by polygon using python and QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75086)